# get drop down value using dojo

Tags: html, dojo, struts

I have struts code like

```
<html:select property="ce">
  <html:option value = "5">5</html:option>
  <html:option value = "10">10</html:option>
  <html:option value = "15">15</html:option>
</html:select>
<div id="dis">
<div>
```

if a option is selected,dojo should get the valu and multiply by 10 and display that in the div?how to do that.

Comment: using dojo,i couldn't find any

Answer (score 2):

Its sounds like you want something like this in the `<body>` tags:

```
<select dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" onChange="displayValue">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>15</option>
</select>

<div id="displayDiv"></div>
```

and something like this in the `<script>` tags:

```
dojo.require('dijit.form.ComboBox');

function displayValue(val) {
    dojo.byId('displayDiv').innerHTML = (val * 10);
}
```

All assuming, of course, that you understand how to import the dojo.js source, and that your `<body>` tag has some dojo style applied to it (so that the comboBox dijit will render), like

`<body class="tundra">`

Comment: why on earth did this get voted down? ...misuse of what that button was intended for...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type ="text/javascript">function displayValue(combo){
dojo.byId("dis").innerHTML = combo.value * 10;
}</script>
<html:select property="ce" onchange="{displayValue(this);}">
  <html:option value = "5">5</html:option>
  <html:option value = "10">10</html:option>
  <html:option value = "15">15</html:option>
</html:select>
<div id="dis">
<div>
```